# Get chars after last , (comma) country

Tags: loops, query-string

I want to get last chance of comma (,) in a $country. But how do I do it?

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
  $country_id = $country['ID'];
  $country = get_the_title().", "; //comma

  echo "<pre>";var_dump($country);echo "</pre>";
  //string(6) "Taiwan, "
  //string(8) "Tanzania, "
  //string(14) "United Kingdom, "

  echo rtrim($country,", ");    //Works not: Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom,
  echo substr($country, 0, strlen($country)-1); //Works not: Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom,
  echo substr($country, 0, -1); //Works not: Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom,
  echo implode(", ", $country); //Works not: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
  echo $country[-1] = PHP_EOL;  //Works not: (empty)
  echo substr($country, -1);    //Works not: (empty)
  echo substr(trim($country), 0, -1); //Works not: Taiwan Tanzania United Kingdom
  echo str_replace(', ', '', $country); //Works not: TaiwanTanzaniaUnited Kingdom
  echo str_replace('', ', ', $country); //Works not: Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom,

}
```

I want to set all the , (comma), except the last one. I have to go Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom, or Taiwan Tanzania United Kingdom. But I prefer Taiwan, Tanzania, United Kingdom.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$c=0;
foreach ($countries as $country) {
  $country_id = $country['ID'];
  $country = get_the_title();

  // Add comma only if it is NOT the last $country
  if (count($countries)-1 != $c) $country .= ", ";

  // display it
  echo $country;
  $c++;
}
```

OR

```
  $c='';
  foreach ($countries as $country) {
      $country_id = $country['ID'];
      $c .= get_the_title().", "; //comma
  }

  // remove comma from last country and display it
  echo rtrim($c,", ");
```